How can I answer a question when I can't find any "answer" button? And why can it ever happen?
I want to answer this question, but on that page I cannot find any button or link like "answer". Is this a technical problem with the Stack Exchange engine or is this that I have insufficient reputation? (Mine seems to be over 2000). What can I do if I know an answer?

That is not a question. That is a blog post. As for not being able to answer a question question, that happens if a question has been marked as 'closed.'

Please carefully look at the URL bar when you visit that link. Notice anything different from usual? Then look carefully at the page. Notice anything that looks different in the sidebar from usual? Notice a word in the top-left corner of the page, next to the Stack Overflow logo, that doesn't say "Stack Overflow"?

@CPlus How do I  tell a blog post from a question, which can be answered?

The answer button is at the very bottom.

@AlexanderGelbukh How do you tell whether you're on stackoverflow or reddit?

Well, for one thing, the page looks completely different. For another, the URL is on an entirely separate domain. For a third, the only "question" written there is immediately "answered" in the next sentence. For a fourth, the text underneath that very obviously doesn't look anything like a valid Stack Overflow question. For example, it's hard to imagine a question that makes sense to ask on Stack Overflow, that also starts with "On this episode:".

@AlexanderGelbukh For example, if it has vote buttons, a views count, etc.

@CPlus Ok, your comment seems to  clarify the situation. Please convert it to an answer, for me to accept it.

The post you linked is a Stack Overflow blog post, not a Stack Overflow question. You cannot 'answer' a blog post. You can tell the blog by the absence of vote buttons, view counts, a usercard with badges and reputation, and by the stackoverflow.blog domain instead of stackoverflow.com/questions, and the differing layout of the webpage.
A 'real' question cannot be answered if the question was closed or locked.
